# K-folds vs 'all possible k-folds'

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit learn's 'KFoldStratified' for a classification task where I have 64 samples, evenly split across 8 labels. I notice the folds are as follows:

Test 0, 8, 16...

Train 1...7, 9... 15

Where the first element of each label is used in the test set and the remainder in the test set. The same situation is set up for the 2nd element, 3rd element, etc.

I'm curious if there is a way (or if it would be desirable to) create a broader set of splits. For instance in addition to the one above, having a test set with the first element of label 1 and the second element of label 2. I realize these splits add a lot of time to the procedure, but I'm wondering if there is a obvious reason not to do this, and if there isn't, how to approach it (as the KFoldStratified doc doesn't make any apparent mention of this kind of change).